# How can i insert the value of two column combine into table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table defined as class - Id, Date, Time, Session, Remark 
Int is auto incremented 
Date,Time and Remark will be added automatically

Session should be the concatenate of (Date + Time)

Suppose Date and Time is varchar(50)

Insert into class (Date,Time,Session,Remark) Values ('a','b', Concat(Date + Time),'c')

Example:
Date - 12/12/2012
Time - 9:00 - 11:00am
Then --> 
Session - 12/12/2012 9:00-11:00am

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: @fa06 i have edited above!

Answer (score 0):

Why not you have used `CONCAT` if Session is `VARCHAR` data type

> ```
> INSERT INTO t VALUES(CONCAT('2019-01-12', '12:00'))
> ```

Comment: i use concat(date,time) for the session but getting error

Comment: @WYMOWaiYan https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab0df4a8a1f1076d67c796d2620c2a4b check this here it works

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write like following query if you are using proper data types, Date for [Date] and Time for [Time].

```
INSERT INTO [YOUR_TABLE]([DATE], [TIME], [SESSION], REMARK)
VALUES (@DATE, @TIME, CAST(@DATEAS DATETIME) + CAST(@TIME AS DATETIME),@REMARK)
```

Comment: Do you mean like this?
Insert into class (Date, time, Session, Remark) VALUES ('a', 'b', Cast(Date + Time), 'c')

Comment: can you tell me sample value of date and time?

Comment: Date - 12/12/2012
Time - 9:00 - 11:00am

Session - 12/12/2012 9:00-11:00am

Comment: and what is the datatype? varchar or date and time

Comment: its just VARCHAR(50)

Comment: in that case what you are doing is correct    Insert into class (Date,Time,Session,Remark) Values ('a','b', Concat(Date + Time),'c')

Comment: I get invalid column name for the Concat(Date + Time)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
CREATE TABLE #date (dt datetime)

declare @date Varchar(20) ='2019-01-29' 
declare @time Varchar(20)='11:06:31.095' 

INSERT INTO #date 
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime,Cast(@date as Datetime))+ CONVERT(datetime,Cast(@time as Datetime))

select * from #date
```

You can replace `@date` with date column and `@time` with time column.

Comment: date and time is VARCHAR data type not dateTime

Comment: @WYMOWaiYan Updated answer according to varchar datatype.